# Playwright's page.waitForResponse gets wrong response

Tags: javascript, typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, playwright

I'm trying to make assertions on XHR, but can't find a right way on how to grab the correct request.

The task is simple: click a button, then wait for network request and make assertions on it's response and request bodies.

The problem is that before I call `changePageSize()` function in my tests, there are already multiple requests in my network with the exact same URLs and methods. The only difference between them is request and response body, so it happens that my code just grabs the first request that matches url I provided. Is there an any way on how to specify the exact network request that I want to use in my tests?

Here is the function:

```
  static async changePageSize(selector: string): Promise<any> {
    const [resp]: any = await Promise.all([
      page.waitForResponse(`**${paths.graph}`),
      this.setPagination(selector),
    ]);
    return [resp]
  }
```

And then I'm using it in my tests:

```
    const [response] = await myPage.changePageSize(selector);

    expect(await response.text()).toContain(`${size}`);
    expect(response.request().postData()).toContain(`${size}`);
```

Comment: You could vote for this request https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4535

Comment: Already did
Thank you @hardkoded!